# NFS stale file handle for regular user but not root

Tags: linux-networking, nfs, kerberos, freeipa

I've installed freeipa container on a Ubuntu server and an NFS server on the server itself. When I mount the NFS directory on a client machine or even the server itself, I can view the mounted directory as root. However, as a regular user, I get stale file handle. I am not using SELinux, and it happens with autofs as well.

My /etc/exports:

```
/home   @netibglabservers(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p)
```

My mount command:

```sh
sudo mount golgi.******.ac.il:/home /mnt/test
```

As a regular user:

```sh
ls /mnt/test/<br/>
ls: cannot open directory '/mnt/test/': Stale file handle
```

As root:

```sh
sudo ls /mnt/test<br/>
ibg  ibglocal  localadmin  yuval  yuvallocal
```

Credentials:

```
klist<br/>
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:96600001:krb_ccache_aGcxW72<br/>
Default principal: yuval@******.AC.IL<br/>
<br/>
Valid starting       Expires              Service principal<br/>
12/27/2021 16:38:59  12/28/2021 16:38:56  nfs/golgi.******.ac.il@******.AC.IL<br/>
12/27/2021 16:38:56  12/28/2021 16:38:56  krbtgt/******.AC.IL@******.AC.IL<br/>
<br/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Yuval.

Comment: Is the user id existing on both the server and client? did you try setting up an anongid/anonuid option?

Comment: I'm using freeipa to manage the identities centrally. I'm able to log in to the user on the client and server and the id-s are the same and derived from the central server.

Comment: What are the rights on the source /home and /mnt/test directory (output of `stat`?)

Comment: I don't have access to the server until Monday. I'll post info on Monday.

Comment: Hi I've reinstalled the server, and reconnected the clients. Things seem to be working correctly. I think the problem was the credentials of the users, but thanks for all the help.